# Configure Ckeditor using dependency in java project

Tags: java, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to integrate ckeditor on maven project. I am able to get dependency but did not work. Is there any way to use ckeditor in jsp (like maven dependency) without downloading the standalone ckeditor. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CKSource doesn't offer any CKEditor/Maven integration. Perhaps you have used some third-party creation which doesn't work or is no longer maintained.

CKEditor is a JavaScript application so it can integrate into any web framework. You will need to download the package or by using CDN link to implement CKEditor.